# why opening more than one Emulator while running?

Tags: android-emulator

While doing programs I normally use AVD Manager to open the emulator, but nowadays while I am running a program a new emulator is being opened automatically, it also takes a long time almost 10-15 minutes. Can somebody please help to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If ou press run in eclipse and it cannot see a connected device, sometimes devices/emulators fail to connect to the adb daemon so even if they are open they are not connected it will automatically launch an android emulator to fulfil the request which will be the default emulator in the AVD list. The reason it is slow is because you are using an arm image and that emulator is just really really slow, what you will want to do is set up an AVD to use an x86 image, you might need to download this through the android sdk manager first if you haven't already and then follow the information at: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html to get it set up to work as fast as possible (HAXM, graphics acceleration etc)